# Insert rows of missing subcategory with corresponding value as zero in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I currently have a `.csv` data file with contents like:

```
Name Fruit Qty
Tauwen Apple 32
Tauewn Pear 09
Wikfae Apple 09
Moigaw Pear 16
```

I want to use R to insert the missing "Pear" for "Wikfae" with corresponding Qty as 0, and missing "Apple" for "Moigaw" with corresponding Qty as 0. So the output table I want is:

```
Name Fruit Qty
Tauwen Apple 32
Tauewn Pear 09
Wikfae Apple 09
Wikfae Peak 0 #Added line
Moigaw Pear 16
Moigaw Apple 0 #Added line
```

I don't even know where to begin. A `tidyverse`-based solution would be most useful for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `complete`:

```
library(tidyr)

df |>
  complete(Name, Fruit, fill = list(Qty = "0"))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Name   Fruit Qty  
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 Moigaw Apple 0    
2 Moigaw Pear  16   
3 Tauwen Apple 32   
4 Tauwen Pear  09   
5 Wikfae Apple 09   
6 Wikfae Pear  0
```

You might however consider turning `Qty` into a numeric:

```
df |>
  mutate(Qty = as.numeric(Qty)) |>
  complete(Name, Fruit, fill = list(Qty = 0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Name   Fruit   Qty
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 Moigaw Apple     0
2 Moigaw Pear     16
3 Tauwen Apple    32
4 Tauwen Pear      9
5 Wikfae Apple     9
6 Wikfae Pear      0
```

Data without typos:

```
library(readr)

df <- 
  read_table("Name Fruit Qty
              Tauwen Apple 32
              Tauwen Pear 09
              Wikfae Apple 09
              Moigaw Pear 16")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but from what it sounds like, you are wanting to surgically add rows into your data. This can be done simply using `add_row`. First I simulated your data:

```
#### Simulate Data ####
Name <- c("Tauwen","Tauwen","Wikfae","Moigaw")
Fruit <- c("Apple","Pear","Apple","Pear")
Qty <- c(32,09,09,16)
tib <- tibble(
  Name,
  Fruit,
  Qty
)
```

Then I added rows, first by a specific placement (`.before` here says which row to place it before), then adding a row at the end.

```
#### Add Rows ####
tib %>% 
  add_row(Name = "Wikfae", 
          Fruit = "Peak",
          Qty = 0,
          .before = 4) %>% 
  add_row(Name = "Moigaw", 
          Fruit = "Apple",
          Qty = 0)
```

Giving you this:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Name   Fruit   Qty
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
1 Tauwen Apple    32
2 Tauwen Pear      9
3 Wikfae Apple     9
4 Wikfae Peak      0
5 Moigaw Pear     16
6 Moigaw Apple     0
```

If your goal is simply to complete observations in a dataframe with these values already existing in some way, then the other answer by Harre here is likely a better choice.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I have marked Harre's solution as "correct", but thanks for your suggestion. Your method would be useful to make other manual entries.

Comment: No worries. Glad his answer was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the long way of @harre's preferable answer:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  summarise(cur_data()[seq(2),]) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Fruit = if(first(Fruit) == "Pear") replace(Fruit, is.na(Fruit), "Apple") 
         else replace(Fruit), is.na(Fruit), first(Fruit)) %>% 
  mutate(Qty = replace_na(Qty, 0)) %>% 
  select(Name, Fruit, Qty)
```

```
  Name   Fruit   Qty
  <chr>  <chr> <int>
1 Moigaw Pear     16
2 Moigaw Apple     0
3 Tauwen Apple    32
4 Tauwen Pear      9
5 Wikfae Apple     9
6 Wikfae Apple     0
```